# Provide an example of a set $A$ and a binary operation $*$ on $A$ such that $(a *b)^2$ does not equal $a^2 * b^2$ for some $a,b \in A$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Provide an example of a set $A$ and a binary operation $*$ on $A$ such that $(a *b)^2$ does not equal $a^2 * b^2$ for some $a,b \in A$.

I said $A = \{1,2\}$.

(1 + 2)^2 does not equal 1^2 + 2^2 
9 does not equal 5 
Is this right can I do this as an example

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  It's not clear from the question whether $(a*b)^2$ means the square of $(a*b)$ as a real number or $(a*b)*(a*b)$

Comment: If your operation is regular addition, then $(1+2)^2=(1+2)+(1+2)=5$, so that's not an example.

Comment: Let's be careful. The usual definition of a binary operation on a set $A$ is a function $A \times A \rightarrow A.$ Your operation takes you outside of your set $A.$

Answer (score 2):

A somewhat more sophisticated collection of examples: let $G$ be a group and

$a, b \in G; \tag 1$

then

$(ab)^2 = abab; \tag 2$

if

$(ab)^2 = a^2b^2, \;  \forall a, b \in G, \tag 3$

then

$abab = a^2b^2 \Longrightarrow ba = ab, \forall a, b \in G,  \tag 4$

and so $G$ must be abelian; thus any non-abelian group provides a counterexample.